# Flutter - run code before or after execution of Function() that was passed as a parameter

Tags: flutter, dart

Example: a widget, that accepts a `Function() function` as a parameter. Now i want to execute code inside this widget, when `function` is called somewhere above in hierarchy, before or after it. Is this possible?

Here is the button widget

```
class AppButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function()? onPressed;

  const AppButton(
      {Key? key,required this.onPressed}): super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(onPressed: onPressed);
  }
```

Here is how I call it

```
     AppButton(
        onPressed: () {
          [some code]
        },
      ),
```

Now the question is: is it possible to call a code, like setState **inside** the AppBar, before or after [some code] gets executed on tap? Like to inject code into `onPressed` inside `AppButton`?

Comment: Can you include some code-with comments, what and how you like to excute ? I'm not getting `function is called somewhere above in hierarchy`

Comment: If you are defining the function inside a variable and passing it to the widget. Then cant make a call to that function unless your widget triggers a onPressed property or something. Please elaborate your query or provide some code snippet you have written.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, You should take the Function() function as an argument and in the Widget(e.g ElevatedButton in the property onPressed: function)

and in the Constructor get the function.
so, when you calling the widget it will ask for the function as well their you will give the function like this

```
YouWidgetName(function: () {
// here will be your code for that particular area.
}),
```